# Missing pages in Knauss' "Introduction to Physical Oceanography, 2nd edition"?

Tags: oceanography

"Introduction to Physical Oceanography, 2nd edition" by John Knauss is a popular oceanography textbook. I bought a copy. It ends at page 308, apparently in the middle of the index. (It seems unlikely that the index would end at "tidal," without having entries for such oceanography favorites as "water, "wind," and "waves.")

I sent an inquiry to the publisher. The publisher was not helpful. I sent the book back to the vendor, and requested a replacement. The replacement was identical.

Does anyone have a copy of the book with index pages beyond 308? Or are they all like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I own the Second edition, 2005 reissue of this textbook, purchased through Amazon in August 2009.

After p308, my copy has only one more page of content (p309), which is the last page of the Index. You indeed have a faulty copy. I recommend you send it back for replacement again and request them to inspect the copy before shipping.

If you are still unlucky with the second replacement, I would try e-mailing the publisher with your purchase invoice and request a pdf of the book which would complement your hardcopy with the missing page.